# Flask: redirecting nonexistent URL's

Tags: python, web, flask

I was given instructions to do the following: modify an app.py file so that my website responds to all possible URLs (aka nonexistent extension like '/jobs', meaning that if an invalid URL is entered, it is redirect to the home index.html page. Here is a copy of my app.py as it stands, any ideas on how to do this?

```
from flask import Flask, render_template  #NEW IMPORT!!

app = Flask(__name__)    #This is creating a new Flask object

#decorator that links...

@app.route('/')                                 #This is the main URL
def index():
    return render_template("index.html", title="Welcome",name="home")       

@app.route('/photo')
def photo():
    return render_template("photo.html", title="Home", name="photo-home")

@app.route('/about')
def photoAbout():
    return render_template("photo/about.html", title="About", name="about")

@app.route('/contact')
def photoContact():
    return render_template("photo/contact.html", title="Contact", name="contact")

@app.route('/resume')
def photoResume():
    return render_template("photo/resume.html", title="Resume", name="resume")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)     #debug=True is optional
```

Comment: http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/57/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think that what you are looking for is probably just error handling. The Flask documentation has a section that shows how to do [error handling](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/errorpages/#custom-error-pages).

But to summarize the important points from there:

```
from flask import render_template

@app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(e):
    return render_template('404.html'), 404
```

You have an app instance, so you can just add this to your code. It's pretty clear that anytime there is a 404 or page does not exist, *404.html* will be rendered.

Assuming you are working with jinja templates *404.html*s contents could be:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block title %}Page Not Found{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
  <h1>Page Not Found</h1>
  <p>What you were looking for is just not there.
  <p><a href="{{ url_for('index') }}">go somewhere nice</a>
{% endblock %}
```

This requires a base template (here *layout.html*). Say for now you don't want to work with jinja templating, just use this as a *404.html*:

```
  <h1>Page Not Found</h1>
  <p>What you were looking for is just not there.
  <p><a href="{{ url_for('index') }}">go somewhere nice</a>
```

In your case because you want to see the home page (*index.html* probably):

```
@app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(e):
    return render_template('index.html'), 404
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. why does that function definition says that >>>Invalid argument name "e" ?

Comment: Coincidentally, the link you provided itself results in a custom 404 page now. Information on error-handling can instead be found (as of today) at http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/errorhandling/#error-handlers

Comment: Recently updated the link to point to the new error handling docs.